# Facebook doesn't open my new app (Content is unavailable error)

Tags: facebook-apps

I made an app for Facebook (my first one) and I wanted to link my blog to my fan page. When I click the tab in my fan page (which should direct my fans to my blog) the page that is shown says that the **content is unavailable** as the page is not trusted. I get the error   `ssl_error_bad_cert_domain`. Why is this? the urls in question are:

http://sigxronopaidagogio.blogspot.com
https://www.facebook.com/sinchronopaidagogeio    https://www.facebook.com/sinchronopaidagogeio/app_429582450457633

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> I made an app for Facebook (my first one) and I wanted to link my blog to my fan page. When I click the tab in my fan page (which should direct my fans to my blog)

Please read the [Platform Polices](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) – it’s explicitly stated in there that the sole purpose of page tab apps **must not be** to direct users away from Facebook; but it sounds like that’s exactly what you want to do.

> the page that is shown says that the content is unavailable as the page is not trusted. I get the error ssl_error_bad_cert_domain. Why is this?

Because your server has no valid SSL certificate for the domain www.sigxronopaidagogeio.blogspot.com.

A working SSL connection is required for apps on Facebook.